# escape characters in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

how do i escape special characters for to_tsquery in psycopg2 python?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build your own parser.

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer? Why do I need to build a parser?

Comment: @goh: if there was a generally accepted answer to this, he'd have added a link.

Comment: Building one's own parser all by oneself for anything that's going into production is generally a miserable, ***terrible*** idea.